# MongoDB shell is not maintaining command history

Tags: mongodb

In my MongoDB shell the command history is lost the moment I come out of it. How to configure it to remember the commands?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know what's the theory behind it, but from my experience:

- if you quit the command line with `Ctrl+C` or `exit` command, history is kept;
- if you quit by closing the command line window (red cross on Windows 7), or with `quit()` command, history is not kept, but the previous history of properly closed windows is not erased.

That's not really "configuration" but it works for me (Windows - mongo 2.6.1).

Comment: For me, even if I quit it using quit(), it still doesnt store the command history. I havent changed any config file or anything, very strange.

Comment: Same for me with `quit()`: must be the same that the red cross. Just try `exit` or `Ctrl+C`.

Comment: Awesome, @dgiugg as you explained, the command history is maintained when I use Ctrl+C . Strange, I expected quit() to be more graceful and it to maintain the command history :)

Comment: That's the opposite behavior from bash, which only will save history when you exit using "logout". Ctrl-C tends to loose it.

Answer (score 0):

History file should be in `~/.dbshell`

Comment: When i open ~/.dbshell I see an empty file. Is there a way to configure mongodb to start storing command history?